# java mail --how to convert String to message in java mail api?

Tags: jakarta-mail

i have to check for the attachments in the mail thrugh java. For that firstly getting the multipart object of the message through getcontent() as follows.

Multipart mp=(Multipart)msg.getContent()

but even if mail have attachment and the message part is simple text then it throws an exception as -- java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.mail.Multipart

So how to get attachments for simple message mails..?

thanks..in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MimeMessage constructor which accepts an InputStream.

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(mySession, 
        new ByteArrayInputStream(myString.getBytes()));
```

See [JavaMail documentation](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#MimeMessage%28javax.mail.Session,%20java.io.InputStream%29)